# Cross window js interaction between a popup and another window of the same domain

Tags: javascript, dom, window, popupwindow

I'm trying to open a popup from window `a` at example.com. then close window `a` and open another window `b` at the same domain (example.com). Is it possible to access the DOM of window `a` from window `b` and how?

The popup is opened from window `a` by

```
window.open('http://example.com/blah', 'somename', settings..),
```

Executing the same from window `b` with a different url (shown below) works

```
window.open("http://example.com/blah2", "somename" ...)
```

This seems to suggest windows are accessed by window name. But I could not find any way to access to DOM of the popup with or without the window's name. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
var newWind = window.open('http://example.com/blah', 'somename',settings);
if (newWind.opener == null) {
    newWind.opener = window;
}
// here you can access DOM of new window
var newDoc = newWind.document;
```

Comment: this way popup window reloads the url, is it possible to access the dom without reloading the url?

Comment: oh.. 
var newWind = window.open('', 'somename',settings); gives access to window, where window.open('sameurl', 'somename', settings)
 loads url again. thanks ..

Comment: But it's not "live".  It seems the Opener gets a local copy of the DOM tree, but not access to the actual DOM tree that's in the other window.  The Opener can make changes to the local copy, but the changes are not reflected in the opened window, and such changes are mostly useless.  Furthermore, I am skeptical that the modification "newWind.opener = window;" has any benefit, i.e. I am skeptical whether the actual window referenced by "newWind" will have access to such a modification.