# playframework: jQuery: append an element to a list from a view, onclick button from another view

Tags: jquery, playframework, append, html-lists

So i have this two views :

> 1.`viewarea.scala.html`

```
@(name:String, tags:String, id:String)
@Main("Area") {
....
<ul id="areaFeat">

//the ul that I want to fill

</ul>
</div>
}
```

> 2.`areaDescription.scala.html`

```
@(id:String)
@Main("Description Area"){

    <form action="@routes.Application.PostAreaDescription(id)" method="POST">
            <textarea cols="40" rows="5" class="form-control" name="textarea"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" id="postDescArea">
    </form>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#postDescArea').click(function(){

      alert("clicked...");

      $("#areaFeat").append('<li><a href="@routes.Application.viewDescription(id)">Description</a></li>');

            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

I just want that `li` element to be added to the `ul` (from the first view) when that button is pushed.
My `alert` goes on ... but  I can't append the `li` ... I do not know what I am  doin' wrong ... Can someone please help ? 
 Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not know what I am doin' wrong?

`viewarea.scala.html` and `areaDescription.scala.html` are different page(as you dint include `viewarea` in `areaDescription`).You are calling ul tag id which is on other page.
To confirm you can also check your browser console.Also check [is it use JavaScript in one document to change HTML in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493689/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-in-one-document-to-change-html-in-another)

Comment: I know that ... Is there a way to put that li to that ul? I will try to put my script in the Main view, maybe then it will work ...

Comment: @flori did you put both form and script in main?

Comment: I have imported the script in Main and these pages are using the @Main template ...

Comment: @flori but they are different document you cant do that see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493689/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-in-one-document-to-change-html-in-another

Comment: ok, I understand ... thank you.... i hoped i can ...  ! I have some id's there ... so i can not put them in the same document. I will think at something else.