# Modify HTML value of a page from another page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

Consider an `HTML` page named `page1.html` with the following simple structure:

```
<html>
<title>Page1</title>
<body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to change`<h1>` text on `page1.html` with JavaScript from `page2.html`?

If it’s possible, how can one achieve this?

Comment: Do you show page2.html?

Comment: Should the change be persistent (i.e. like editing Wikipedia, after you do the action on `page2.html` then the `h1` on `page1.html` will be set to the new value for all that load the page after that point), or does it need to be dynamic and only to the person that currently has the page open (i.e. like Facebook chat, where you send a message to one user, and it appears on the other user's screen)?

Comment: actually I didn't provide any code for page2.html, but I was Curious that, is the problem feasible? and then how it could be implemented?

Comment: I do not want to make changes persistent but just change the needed value for current load.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: actually, i have an alarm system which generates alarms in a web page while i do not have access to the source code of the program, but i want to acknowledge those alarms by scripting on another page so the acknowledgement process can be done automatically by my script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use JavaScript in one document to change HTML in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493689/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-in-one-document-to-change-html-in-another)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you serve both your `HTML`S from the same origin (e.g. if you had two facebook tabs open), you could solve this by using the ['storage' event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/storage) (Local Storage is shared between tabs), like this:

HTML1:

```
<script>
    localStorage.setItem('message', JSON.stringify({ 'myContent': 'i like pizza' }));`
     localStorage.removeItem('message');
</script>
```

HTML2

```
<script>
    $(window).on('storage', e => {
        var message = JSON.parse(e.originalEvent.newValue);
        $('#myH1').text(message.myContent);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How is `storage` an `event`?

Comment: thanks to iuliu.net for the answer, but as i said, i do not aim to make any modification in page1.html

Comment: Yes. Using this example, the changes will not be persisted, they'll be there just for the current load. (don't be fooled by seeing localStorage here, it's nothing but a communication mechanism between the two pages)

Answer (score 2):

I think the short answer you are looking for is "No".

You cannot modify one static page using another static page without a server between them.

Some solutions as mentioned from other pals can work, like using a local storage or stuffing a cookie -Only if they will run on the same browser-, but it will definitely require some changes in page1.html which is not you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you commented that you don’t need it to be persistent, what you want is to create an illusion that you’re changing `<h1>` text on `page1.html` with JavaScript from `page2.html`.

You need two things:

1. First, to change the actual text in `<h1>` use `.innerText` property with `replace()` method.
2. To change the URL in the address bar from `/page2.html` to `/page1.html` use the `History API` with `history.pushState()` and `history.replaceState()` methods.

Comment: Btw, I’m still not entirely sure what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: can I perform number 1 in page2.html?

Comment: Since `page2.html` is virtual, then the answer is yes.

Comment: actually, i have an alarm system which generates alarms in a web page while i do not have access to the source code of the program, but i want to acknowledge those alarms by scripting on another page so the acknowledgement process can be done automatically by my script.

Comment: If I understood correctly, what you want can’t be done.

Comment: page2.html is not virtual, it is the only html file which i want to perform my script in it, and I do not aim to perform any modifications in page1.html code.

Comment: So you want to read alarm status from the original page and update the status on yours?

Comment: yes and this update should change a value of an HTML element (as instance: a checkbox) on page1