# How can I change a value from another js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a constants.js file like that:

```
var keyvalues = {
    "var1": 0.08,
    "var2": 0.08,
    "var3": 0.07,
    "var4": 0.065
}
```

And I want to change value from another js file.

My app.js file like that:

```
app.post('/updateValue', (req, res)=>{
    let a = constants.keyvalues
    const existingKey = req.body.key;
    const newValue = req.body.newvalue;
    
    constants.keyvalues[existingKey] = newValue; =======> (1)
})
```

(1) : in this line I want to update value from constant.js file.

And my app.js file will on production stage. I want to use this endpoint for update some values **physically**.

What is the right way for changing values on constants.js file from app.js file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244361/can-i-access-variables-from-another-file

Comment: They're not really constants if they can change, eh?  Do they need to persist across restarts of the service? If so you need to write those values somewhere (file, database, etc.) and reload them when things start up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use JavaScript in one document to change HTML in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493689/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-in-one-document-to-change-html-in-another)

Comment: @ahmed gaafer as with the answer that I deleted.  I didn't notice the node.js tag on the question so the your link and my answer doesn't work the same.  He needs to do the module export stuff like crashes answer below

Comment: Just changing the value of a variable in memory will not actually change the value hardcoded in you javascript program for this variable - and thus the change will not persist across program restarts. You would need to read these values from a configuration file, and save back any changes there.

Comment: It is better to keep this constants values in db table/collection. So It would be easy to update according by API, In case of need

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to export the object.

If you're working with ES5, use

```
let keyValues = {...};
module.exports = {keyValues}
```

ES6 equivalent:

```
let keyValues = {...};
export {keyValues};
```

In the file where you want to access the object, use this

```
const {keyValues} = require("path/to/constants");
console.log(keyValues)
keyValues[key] = value
```

ES6 Equivalent:

```
import {keyValues} from 'path/to/constants';
console.log(keyValues)
keyValues[key] = value
```